# Insert variable and PDF tag into PHP code

Tags: php

This should be incredibly simple but i can't seem to figure it out.

I have the following code

```
<?php
$bookingid='12345';
    include_once('phpToPDF.php') ;
    //Code to generate PDF file from specified URL
    phptopdf_url('https://google.com/','pdf/', $bookingid.pdf);
    echo "<a href='pdf/$bookingid.pdf'>Download PDF</a>";
?>
```

It echo's correctly however when it comes to generate the pdf...

```
phptopdf_url('https://google.com/','pdf/', $bookingid.pdf);
```

...it misses out the fullstop so it generates 12345pdf whereas it should be 12345.pdf.

Again, i apologise for the probable simplicity of this but i can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: `$bookingid . '.pdf'`

Comment: Damn - u_mulder, you beat me :)

`$bookingid.".pdf"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$bookingid.pdf
```

It tells php to concatenate variable `$bookingid` with constant `pdf`. Since constant `pdf` is undefined, it is casted to string and concatenated. Proper code will look like:

```
$bookingid . '.pdf'
```

or

```
"$bookingid.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be

```
$bookingid.".pdf"
```

PHP is seeing a string concatenation, concatenating `pdf`' to `$booking`. `pdf` is an undefined string, so PHP helpfully assumes that you mean the text itself, but it misses the full stop you also need.